# Download images and stores as resources drawable

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I'm trying to reduce the amount of my apps. One of the thing is to remove some pictures (bitmap) from the apk and download the images later if user click on it. My question is, can the later pictures are stored as resources and access using getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. However, you can save these to the device's storage and read them from there. Please refer to the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal